# Python ttkwidgets - Dynamically update AutocompleteCombobox completevalues list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttkwidgets

I have a tkinter form on which I have 2 comboboxes. The options in the second combobox depend on what has been selected in the first one. When I use a pair of ttk.Combobox widgets, everything works OK, but if I change these to ttkwidgets.AutocompleteCombobox widgets, the second list does not populate and, strangely, I get a "TypeError: config() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Is it possible to dynamically set the entries list for an AutocompleteCombobox and, if so, how?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the `ttkwidgets.AutocompleteCombobox`, it looks like you're supposed to call the `set_completion_list` method if you want to change the list of completions.